# How to run code every x seconds inside while true - python

Tags: python, while-loop, repeat

I need to execute code inside while loop every x seconds without stoping loop work

I have trying threading and lock combinations but it is still not working. I am working on python 3.7.4, pycharm 2019.2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import configparser
import logging
import threading
import time

import ts3

__all__ = ["notify_bot"]

logging.basicConfig(filename='ts3bot.log',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
                    )

logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
def notify_bot(ts3conn, config, lock):
    logging.info("Start Notify Bot ...")
    lock.acquire()
    ts3conn.exec_("servernotifyregister", event="server")
    lock.release()
    while True:
        event = ts3conn.wait_for_event()
        try:
            reasonid_ = event[0]["reasonid"]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        if reasonid_ == "0":
            logging.info("User joined Lobby:")
            logging.info(event[0])
            servergroups = event[0]['client_servergroups']
            guestname = event[0]['client_nickname']
            lock.acquire()
            if not set(servergroups):
                print(f"s1 {guestname}")
            else:
                print(f"s2{guestname}")
            lock.release()
    return None
def keep_alive(ts3conn, lock):
    while True:
        logging.info("Send keep alive!")
        lock.acquire()
        ts3conn.send_keepalive()
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("Start TS Bot ...")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read("settings_test.ini")
    logging.info("Config loaded!")
    HOST = config['server']['url']
    PORT = config['server']['query_port']
    USER = config['server']['query_user']
    PASS = config['server']['query_pw']
    SID = config['server']['sid']
    NAME = config['bot']['name']

    logging.info("Connecting to query interface ...")
    URI = f"telnet://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOST}:{PORT}"
    try:
        with ts3.query.TS3ServerConnection(URI) as ts3conn:
            ts3conn.exec_("use", sid=SID)

            ts3conn.query("clientupdate", client_nickname="x123d")
            logging.info("Connected!")

            lock = threading.Lock()

            notify_thread = threading.Thread(target=notify_bot, args=(ts3conn, config, lock), daemon=True,
                                             name="notify")
            keep_alive_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_alive, args=(ts3conn, lock), daemon=True,
                                                 name="keep_alive")
            notify_thread.start()
            keep_alive_thread.start()
            keep_alive_thread.join()
            notify_thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.INFO(60 * "=")
        logging.info("TS Bot terminated by user!")
        logging.INFO(60 * "=")
```

After run work for 1 person who join server and do nothing, dont send keep alive and dont work at all

Comment: `time` module will help. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: @Poojan: The questioner is already using the `time` module and the command `time.sleep(5)` in his code.

Comment: You're talking about your `keep_alive` function?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bibio TIME 
You can check it from official python website (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for simple things, I find the `_thread` library easier. Here's a function that you can run in a thread, and an example of starting that thread:

```
import _thread
def mythread(arg1):
    while True:
        time.sleep(arg1)
        do.whatever()
_thread.start_new_thread(mythread, (5,))
```

The important thing to note is the second argument I passed to the `_thread.start_new_thread` function. It **must** be a tuple, which is why there is a comma after the 5. Even if your function doesn't require any arguments, you have to pass a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I am using time module and threading,
I'v made some changes and it seems to work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import configparser
import logging
import threading
import time
import ts3
logging.basicConfig(filename='ts3bot.log',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
                    )
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

def notify_bot(ts3conn):
    logging.info("Start Notify Bot ...")
    ts3conn.exec_("servernotifyregister", event="server")
    while True:
        event = ts3conn.wait_for_event()
        try:
            reasonid_ = event[0]["reasonid"]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        if reasonid_ == "0":
            logging.info("User joined Lobby:")
            logging.info(event[0])
            servergroups = event[0]['client_servergroups']
            guestname = event[0]['client_nickname']
            if not set(servergroups):
                print(f"s1 {guestname}")
            else:
                print(f"s2{guestname}")
    return None
def keep_alive(ts3conn, time):
    while True:
        logging.info("Send keep alive!")
        ts3conn.send_keepalive()
        time.sleep(20)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("Start TS Bot ...")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read("settings_test.ini")
    logging.info("Config loaded!")
    HOST = config['server']['url']
    PORT = config['server']['query_port']
    USER = config['server']['query_user']
    PASS = config['server']['query_pw']
    SID = config['server']['sid']
    NAME = config['bot']['name']

    logging.info("Connecting to query interface ...")
    URI = f"telnet://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOST}:{PORT}"
    try:
        with ts3.query.TS3ServerConnection(URI) as ts3conn:
            ts3conn.exec_("use", sid=SID)

            ts3conn.query("clientupdate", client_nickname="x123d")
            logging.info("Connected!")
            notify_thread = threading.Thread(target=notify_bot, args=(ts3conn,), daemon=True,
                                             name="notify")
            keep_alive_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_alive, args=(ts3conn, time), daemon=True,
                                                 name="keep_alive")
            notify_thread.start()
            keep_alive_thread.start()
            keep_alive_thread.join()
            notify_thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.INFO(60 * "=")
        logging.info("TS Bot terminated by user!")
        logging.INFO(60 * "=")
```

It looks like ts3conn.send_keepalive() making error, when I delete it, code work fine, when I'v add it, code stop working after send ts3conn.send_keepalive() once